# update_column method for multiple attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Model with some attributes: attr1, attr2 and attr3.
I need to update this attributes without execute callbacks and validations.
I found [update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) method but I want to update the three attributes at the same time. I need something like:

```
update_columns({attr1: val1, attr2: val2, attr3: val3})
```

instead

```
update_column(attr1, val1)
update_column(attr2, val2)
update_column(attr3, val3)
```

Comment: We need to see the code you've written to solve the problem, and why it didn't work. See "[Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)".

Comment: The code is working but I don't want to go three times to the database. I want to go one time an update the three attributes at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `update_columns(attr1: val1, attr2: val2, attr3: val3)` as documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_columns). You just need to pass in the key-value pairs, not an actual hash object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update_attributes!(attr1: val1, attr2: val2, attr3: val3)
```

Perhaps without the `!`, but I think that is needed.

Comment: Using `update_attributes!` won't skip callbacks. It simply doesn't return true or false, but throws an exception if the update failed.